# Adding a static object to a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary

I have a class which is referenced in multiple views, but I would like there to be only one instance of the class shared among them. I have implemented my class like so:

```
using System;

public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way I can add Singleton.Instance to my resource dictionary as a resource?
I would like to write something like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:Singleton.Instance x:Key="MySingleton"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

instead of having to write `{x:static my:Singleton.Instance}` every time I need to reference it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is possible in XAML:

```
<!-- assuming the 'my' namespace contains your singleton -->
<Application.Resources>
   <x:StaticExtension Member="my:Singleton.Instance" x:Key="MySingleton"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) seems to suggest that <x:Static Member="my:Singleton.Instance" x:Key="MySingleton"> should work, so I'm just going to accept this answer.

Comment: If you are aiming at merging it into a resource dictionary you won't need the key.

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <x:Static Member="me:Singleton.Instance"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it is not possible from XAML. But you can add the singleton object to the resources from code-behind:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Resources.Add("MySingleton", Singleton.Instance);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to MSDN the StaticExtension is not available in .NET Client Profile 3.5 or lower. For other versions see the XAML verions in the other answer.